# Enable editing mode just for a section in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` in which there is a section that is editable.

If I enable editing on the entire `tableView`, other cells while in editing mode are not `selectable`, so I need to enable the editing mode only on a specific section so that while other cells are `selectable`, the section is editable.

The reason that I need to set editing is those red square minus buttons that appear next to `deletable` cells.

**Summary:**

I need those red minus buttons next to cells, so I need to set editing as true, but if I do so, other cells won't be `selectable` thus I need to either set editing as true for a specific section, or add those red minus buttons without the editing mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method something like,

**Obj-C**

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if (indexPath.section == 1) {

    return YES;
}

return NO;
}
```

**Swift :**

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return true
    }


    return false
}
```

To enable selection during editing you need to set,

**Obj-C**

```
     self.yourTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

**Swift**

```
     self.yourTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Comment: this method says if cell is editable or not but it doesn't change the fact that while in editing mode cells that are not editable are also not selectable

Comment: For that you have to set  `self.yourTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true`

Comment: exactly, thank you, can you make it as an answer so I can make it the right answer

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4/5**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

more nice to have like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? true : false
}
```